# Zabbix ICMP Template Macro

Tags: macros, templates, icmp, zabbix

I am trying to use a Macro in the ICMP Template to have more flexibilty for my hosts.

In my head I have everything set up correctly, In my trigger view I can see the host is set to alarm warning only if higher than 0.75 which should not be alarmed since my average response time is 66ms.

Please have a look in the album below for screenshots of my current config.

[Zabbix Macro Screenshots (Imgur Album)](https://pidgeonbarbecue.imgur.com)

I am lost in this, really don't know what I am missing.

Any help is greatly appreaciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely trying to alert on 0.75 ms right now. To confirm this, switch to "Values" when viewing the graph (upper right corner) and check what the raw values are like.

Comment: Hello Richlv, thanks for your reply, I can't find an option "Values" on the Graph sreen, I'm using version 3.2 btw.

Comment: Look for a dropdown in the upper right corner. Make sure you are looking at a "simple graph" for that single item, accessible from the "Latest data" page.

Answer (score 0):

It could be problems with ping poller and StartTimers, try to increase both and remember to restart the zabbix server to aplly the changes of the .conf .
I had problems with high response hosts when it was not pinging from CMD, and the macro was correct.
I did those changes and fixed it